# Stacked Diverging Bar Chart Plot by groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I am trying to do a chart like this one:

[image]

The idea is to plot 3 amounts, in this mixed stacked bar chart we have a dataframe which has one row for a negative value and two rows for the positive value, however i need to stack the negative with the first positive bar, i also need 3 colors. The code I have so far is as follows: (the dataframe already has the desired shape):

```
df3 <- read.table(
text = 
"region group metric somevalue
blue T1 epsilon 63
blue T2 epsilon -40
red T1 epsilon 100
blue T1 kappa 19
blue T2 kappa -30
red T1 kappa 75
blue T1 zulu  50
blue T2 zulu -18
red T1 zulu 68", header=TRUE)

p2 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = metric, y = somevalue, fill=region))+
  geom_col(aes(fill = group), width = 0.7) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity')
p2
```

please help me out, if you think the dataframe has to be modified please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacking and dodging is always a bit tricky. In your case this could be achieved like so:

1. Convert `region` to a `factor`. (This makes sure that step 3 works)
2. Split your dataset in two for negative and positive values.
3. Fill up the datasets using tidy::complete so that each dataset contains "all" combinations of metric, region and group. (This makes sure that the dodging works
4. Use two geom_col layers to plot the positive and negative values using `position="dodge"`. I added `na.rm = TRUE` to remove the missing values we added via `complete`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3$region <- factor(df3$region)

df3_neg <- filter(df3, somevalue < 0) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(region, group, metric)

df3_pos<- filter(df3, somevalue > 0) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(region, group, metric)

p2 <- ggplot(df3, aes(somevalue, metric)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = group, fill=region), data = df3_pos, position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = group, fill=region), data = df3_neg, position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(T2 = .6, T1 = 1)) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
p2
```

[image]

**EDIT** Adding annotations could be achieved the same way, e.g. my code below uses two `geom_text` to add the values next to the bar where I make use of `position_dodge2(.9)` so that the labels align nicely with the bars:

```r
p2 <- ggplot(df3, aes(somevalue, metric)) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = group, fill=region), data = df3_pos, position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_col(aes(alpha = group, fill=region), data = df3_neg, position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(x = somevalue + 1, label = somevalue), data = df3_pos, position = position_dodge2(width  = .9), hjust = 0, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(x = somevalue - 1, label = somevalue), data = df3_neg, , position = position_dodge2(width  = .9), hjust = 1, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(T2 = .6, T1 = 1)) +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
p2
```

[image]

**EDIT2** Adding a table is indeed a different thing. In that case I would go for `patchwork` which means making plots to mimic the table layout. To make the dodging work or to make sure that the table rows align with the bars you have make a plot for each table column. The basic approach may look like so:

```r
library(patchwork)

# 1. Make a dataframe with all combinations of region and metric using expand_grid
d_table <- expand_grid(region = unique(df3$region), metric = unique(df3$metric))

# 2. Add columns with the table content
d_table$column1 <- LETTERS[1:6]
d_table$column2 <- letters[1:6]

# 3. Make a plot for each column of the table
p_column1 <- ggplot(d_table, aes(y = metric, x = 1, label = column1)) +
  geom_text(aes(group = region), position = position_dodge2(width = .9), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", breaks = 1, labels = "column1") +
  labs(y = NULL, x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(rep(0, 4), "pt"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA))
p_column2 <- ggplot(d_table, aes(y = metric, x = 1, label = column2)) +
  geom_text(aes(group = region), position = position_dodge2(width = .9), na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", breaks = 1, labels = "column2") +
  labs(y = NULL, x = "") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(rep(0, 4), "pt"), 
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA))
# 4. Add the table columns via patchwork
p2 + p_column1 + p_column2 + plot_layout(widths = c(1, .1, .1))
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to put annotations text to the right of every bar?

Comment: Hi @JKLambert. I just made an edit to show you one approach to add labels via geom_text.

Comment: thank you very much, the actual problem I have is to draw a two column table to the right of this very plot. that table has 2 columns and six rows, I would like to align the bars to the rows of the table. so you could just read one bar and then with your finger jump to the row of the table. the actual table can have 2 columns and other data not used in the plot. do you know how to do this? I am trying ggarrange but that really changes the sizes.... please help.

Comment: I just added an approach using patchwork.

Comment: thanks a lot! just a little advanced for me, could you just put a normal dataframe so I understand what you are doing? a dataframe with two columns, I am gonna need the column names of the table on top of the columns as well... if you happen to do this I owe you 100 points1

Comment: Haha. Have a look at my edit. This should make it clearer. I you still encounter any problems I would suggest you build on my approach if you like and ask a new question. Best S.